# powershell 5.1, [ordered] vs Import-PowerShellDataFile

Tags: powershell

I use `.psd1`-like file to store my script's config and read if with `$config = Import-PowerShellDataFile <path to the file>`, and I'm quite happy with it. eg.

```
@{
    loglevel  = 'verbose'
    mailboxes = @(
      @{ identity = 'foo'; forced = $true  }
      @{ identity = 'bar'; forced = $false }
    )
}
```

in a moment of madness I added `[ordered]` in front of the hastables in the array and suddenly got the `Import-PowerShellDataFile : Exception calling "SafeGetValue" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot generate a Windows PowerShell object for a ScriptBlock evaluating dynamic expressions.` error

```
@{
    loglevel  = 'verbose'
    mailboxes = @(
      [ordered]@{ identity = 'foo'; forced = $true  }
      [ordered]@{ identity = 'bar'; forced = $false }
    )
}
```

I don't see what is suddenly *dynamic* in the config file. is there a way to import ordered hashtables with `Import-PowerShellDataFile`? (yes, it works with `Invoke-Expression`, but I'm not very keen on using it for obvious security reasons)

Comment: Without knowing how PS works internally, I'm going to guess that the type cast `[ordered]` is effectively equivalent to invoking actual code to convert the hash table "on the fly" - and invoking code is not safe, and therefore a violation of what `Import-PowerShellDataFile` does.

Comment: ```[ordered]``` is a “type accelerator” for ```System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary``` - you’re basically declaring an ```OrderedDictionary``` literal instead of a hashtable. They both implement ```IDictionary``` and can be used interchangeably anywhere that supports the interface rather than specifically hashtables, but maybe ```Import-PowerShellDataFile``` isn’t one of those, and wants a hashtable… or maybe the mere presence of a type accelerator is triggering the “dynamic expressions” error…

Comment: Here we go… https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_data_files?view=powershell-7.3#basic-data-files “The Import-PowerShellDataFile cmdlet imports basic data files. The data in the file must be contained in a hashtable. This format only supports constant values. You can't use code or PowerShell expressions”

Comment: @mclayton the top level data structure is a hashtable, all values are constant and no code is present. unless POSH _thinks_ the type accelerator is some kind of code...